# (Nearly) all garbage collections are full collections

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have been collecting performance counters for a managed application over roughly four days. During that time, there have been the following garbage collections:

- Generation 0: 133,695
- Generation 1: 133,413
- Generation 2: 133,254

Some of these are "induced" full collections using `GC.Collect()`. There were 323 over the four days.

Why would all (or, essentially all) my collections be full collections? I am guessing that this circumstance is contributing to a very high "% Time in GC" counter (upwards of 70%, even when allocated bytes/sec drops significantly).

It may or may not be important to note that I'm running .NET 4.0, 64-bit, and using the server GC, per the configuration file.

Comment: We'd have to know more about your application to even be able to make a guess, I would think.

Comment: If you're calling GC.Collect you can't really reason at all about how often each collection is run; you're messing with what it wants to do.  Also, the GC is very dynamic in that it runs collections when it thinks it needs to, meaning this will be *very* dependant on the code that you're running and how much memory you create, at what scope, how long you hold onto it, etc.

Comment: `GC.Collect()` does a full collection of all generations. This is definitely a contributing factor. Test how the numbers change if you remove the explicit collection. Other than that, we can't say much without knowing your application's details.

Comment: @Joel: If you'd like to know more, I'm happy to oblige. What would you like to know?

Comment: @Servy: I doubt very much that one full collection via `GC.Collect()` each 16 minutes is affecting the system very much. I could remove it and verify that, but I'm extremely skeptical.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: I would imagine the numbers would change by being exactly 323 fewer full collections over four days.

Comment: @Mark I of course couldn't prove anything without your code, I'm simply saying that if I'm explicitly going out of my way to figure out how often the GC runs on it's own then explicitly forcing it to run sounds like a big red flag.

Comment: @Mark, by any chance do you happen to have an extremely large number of long-lived objects instantiated at once?  We had this kind of GC performance with a service that had a lookup tree made up of millions of nodes.

Comment: @sgorozco: I don't think so. I'm allocating large amounts of memory (upwards of 300 MB/sec at times), but nothing is particularly long-lived.

Comment: @Mark: If I was allocating 300 MB/s, I'd be surprised not to find the GC extremely busy. You are probably continually filling up gen 1 and 2, thus requiring regular full collections.

Comment: "I'm generating a lot of garbage. Why does the garbage collector seem to spend a lot of time collecting garbage?" Really? ;) If you want to minimize time spent GC'in, aim for few, long-lived allocations. The exact opposite of what you're doing now. :)

Comment: @MarceloCantos My promoted bytes/sec from gen 0 to gen 1 is only about 32K/sec, that doesn't seem very high...

Answer (score 6):

> I'm allocating large amounts of memory (upwards of 300 MB/sec at times)

That's enough to explain what you observe.  This will trigger lots of collections during that second, the gen #0 and gen #1 heaps are not that large.  With a very high likelihood that the objects in these generations are still in use, since they were just allocated, so the gen #0 and 1 collections don't make enough space and just about every object gets promoted to gen #2.  The GC has a countermeasure for this, it will automatically grow the generation sizes.  But that can't keep up with the ravenous hunger for memory you have.  You can use the .NET memory performance counters in Perfmon.exe to observe this.  Any .NET memory profiler will give you insight as well with prettier graphs.

Allocating memory at such a high rate isn't that easy, you must be allocating lots of arrays.  Which in itself would explain it, arrays larger than 85,000 bytes are allocated in the Large Object Heap.  Look for ways to *reuse* those arrays.  Almost all .NET collection classes use arrays under the hood.

Comment: My promoted bytes/sec from gen 0 to gen 1 is only about 32K, that doesn't seem very high. My promoted bytes/sec from gen 1 to gen 2 is just under 4K. That also doesn't seem very high. I'm running the server GC, which, from what I understand, gives me significantly larger heaps?

Comment: @Mark, are you allocating arrays or objects that are bigger than 85,000 bytes? If that's the case, then you are bypassing the normal allocation scheme and falling into what's called the [Large Object Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx), that is a special heap that is reclaimed, but never compacted. That could be a reason why you are not seeing the promotions you expect from generation to generation.  I think Hans is right on the spot in the fact that the garbage collector must be very taxed to keep up with such a high memory demand.  =)

Comment: @sgorozco: Apparently, I am. Using PerfView, I grabbed data for the GC, and just about every collection (792 of 795) was because of AllocLarge.

Comment: @Mark: I think doing as HansPassant suggests (reusing objects or arrays no longer required, if possible) will have a strong performance benefit.  Good Luck!